# Does interpolation search have a time or space complexity?

Tags: algorithm, search, interpolation

I have done some research on interpolations space and time complexity and have failed to find any conclusive results.
So my question is what is the time and space complexity of the interpolation search?
I know it is similar to binary search so but surely it does not have the same time and space complexity as a binary search algorithm?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search).

---

#### Time

Average case: `log(log(n))`

Worst case: `O(n)`

#### Space

You only need to store the indexes in the list for your search, so it's `O(1)`.

Comment: if this for its time or space complexity?

Comment: Edited to give more info.